# React.js Favicon does not change

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, favicon

I am currently coding a React.js application. I want to change the icon, so I deleted the default one and pasted the new one in the public folder. When I start the application, the icon does not change, and it's still the default one. Thanks for any help.

```
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: You will have to tell where you have pasted the icon? are you using CRA?

Comment: I don't know what CRA is. I just replaced the default icon with my icon.

Comment: My bad. Create React App

Comment: Try clearing you cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emptied the cache of my browser, and now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines in your `index.html` if your favicon is in `public > favicon.ico`

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: Still doesn't work :(

Comment: can you empty the cache of your browser or do a ctrl + f5 ?

Comment: Nice emptying the cache works, thank you!